# Microsoft Graph AppRoleAssignments via AD Group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, service-principal

I have multiple Managed Service Identities (MSIs) that need the same set of permissions to use Microsoft Graph. I've given permissions to one of the MSIs directly and I got the expected result (after waiting for permissions to propagate).

To make life easier, I decided to create a security group, give that group the needed permissions, then assign the various MSIs to that security group. I've verified that the AppRoleAssignments are correct for the security group, but the group members do not seem to inherit the access as expected (even after waiting to ensure permissions have had time to propagate).

Does anyone know if this scenario is supported?

Comment: Hi @Brinan Ball ,  Did you set `groupmemberships` in the AAD App to `Security group`?

Comment: Yes, @WayneYang-MSFT, I did. I got an answer from someone else at MSFT. Apologies for not updating here. I'll post an answer and link it to the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question in GitHub and I got my answer there. The net out is that this scenario is not currently supported, however, it may be a supported scenario in the future.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2797